# MCP "Fatal Error" Upon Decompile

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm attempting to install MCP on Mac OS X 10.6. Here is the error and where it takes place:

```
== Updating client ==
> Adding javadoc
> Renaming sources
- Done in 8.85 seconds
FATAL ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jake/Desktop/mcp903/runtime/decompile.py", line 143, in decompile
    keep_lvt=keep_lvt, keep_generics=keep_generics, force_rg=force_rg)
  File "/Users/Jake/Desktop/mcp903/runtime/mcp.py", line 16, in decompile_side
    if not commands.checkjars(side):
  File "/Users/Jake/Desktop/mcp903/runtime/commands.py", line 924, in checkjars
    with open(jarlk[side], 'rb') as fh:
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

`

Java Info:

```
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-10M4509)
```

I've read that you have to add the path to python in the Enviornmental Variables file, but I'm not sure where or how to add that to the file. I'm attempting to decompile 1.7.2.jar and minecraft_server_1.7.2.jar

I can supply more information if needed.

Comment: I suspect that adding python to the PATH is not your problem, since the error says that the python program ran but failed due to a python error.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it then?

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` and `which python`? Mac OS comes with its own custom Python, which the scripts may disagree with.

Comment: Shouldn't this be off-topic? It is about developing minecraft mods

Answer (score 0):

MCP has not yet been updated to 1.7.2, unfortunately.  The update to 1.7.2 most likely caused some directory changes or something of the like that caused MCP to break fatally while decompiling.

Comment: Not true.  MCP 903 is RC1 for 1.7.2.

Comment: Hm.  However, I have not yet seen it on the MCP website nor anywhere else, either.  Anyplace except the latest Forge, it doesn't exist.

Comment: For whatever reason, it's only [posted here on twitter](https://twitter.com/SeargeDP/status/423188497718333440).